# Google Docs API for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-docs-api

Is there a JavaScript API or third party framework for Google Docs that I can use in Node.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google apps allows RESTful api's to access resources. Please refer the protocol guide for the same

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/developers_guide.html

Comment: There isn´t such, so this seems to be the only possibility ;)

Comment: officially deprecated as of September 14, 2012

Answer (score 0):

There are a few plugins to read google spreadsheets though not many to do batch updates. So if you just want to update google spreadsheets, check out: https://github.com/jpillora/node-edit-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Unfortunately this library does not support appending new rows to the current Spreadsheet. http://www.verious.com/code/jpillora/node-edit-google-spreadsheet/ Are there any other libraries you would suggest?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As nelsonic mentions in his reply to nibin012, there is niftylettuce's node-google-drive node.js module:
https://npmjs.org/package/google-drive

Then the Google Drive API there is Google OAuth for "service"/server apps mentioned in the following links:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#scenarios
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

However in the latter link there is no support for a JavaScript library yet.